# Groovy dsl dependency injection

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, dsl

I am running a spring boot app with aws dependencies  (in java), and I have a requirement to build dsl. So i used groovy to build dsl and trying to understand how we can inject autowired beans in dsl method.

```
dsl: 

  sendNotification{
    topic 'topic'
    payload 'payload'
    send()
  }
```

```
Groovy (src/main/groovy)

class SNSDsl{
  String topic
  String payload
  void topic(String topic)
    this.topic = topic
  }
  void payload(String payload) {
    this.payload = payload
  }

  void send(){
    // need to call SNSService sendNotification method
  
  }

}

src/main/java 

@Named
public class SNSService {
  private final SnsOperations snsOperations;
  SNSService (SnsOperations snsOperations){
    this.snsOperations = snsOperations;
  }
  public void sendNotification(final String payload, final String topic) {
        SnsNotification<String> notification = SnsNotification.builder(payload)
                .build();
        snsOperations.sendNotification(topic, notification);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add a (private) property to SNSDsl and pass it on creation. Please add
the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors, stacktraces,
logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Dependency injection in groovy and java is the same. It's not clear what's the problem.